# How can I make TypeScript know which proptypes I am using?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I make TypeScript know which of the prop types the component is receiving?
E.g if `multiple` is true, I want TypeScript to expect that `selectValue` is an array of string or if its not present then TypeScript should expect `selectValue` to be a string.

I really dislike having to cast my props to the appropriate type for TypeScript to be happy.

Here is the current code for my custom `<Select>` component:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import MultipleSelect from './MultipleSelect';
import SingleSelect from './SingleSelect';

interface MultipleSelectProps {
  selectValue: string[];
  multiple: true;
  onSelectChange: (values: string[]) => void;
  renderValue?: (value: string[]) => React.ReactNode;
}

interface SingleSelectProps {
  selectValue: string;
  onSelectChange: (values: string) => void;
  multiple?: never;
  renderValue?: (value: string) => React.ReactNode;
}

type SelectProps = SingleSelectProps | MultipleSelectProps;

const Select: React.FC<SelectProps> = ({
  selectValue,
  multiple,
  onSelectChange,
  renderValue,
  children,
}) => {
  if (multiple) {
    const multipleSelectValue = selectValue as string[];
    const multipleSelectChange = onSelectChange as (value: string[]) => void;
    const multipleRenderValue = renderValue as (value: string[]) => ReactNode;

    return (
      <MultipleSelect
        selectValue={multipleSelectValue}
        onSelectChange={multipleSelectChange}
        renderValue={multipleRenderValue}
      >
        {children}
      </MultipleSelect>
    );
  }

  const singleSelectValue = selectValue as string;
  const singleSelectChange = onSelectChange as (value: string) => void;
  const singleRenderValue = renderValue as (value: string) => ReactNode;

  return (
    <SingleSelect
      selectValue={singleSelectValue}
      onSelectChange={singleSelectChange}
      renderValue={singleRenderValue}
    >
      {children}
    </SingleSelect>
  );
};
export default Select;
```

I want to write it something like this instead:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import MultipleSelect from './MultipleSelect';
import SingleSelect from './SingleSelect';

interface MultipleSelectProps {
  selectValue: string[];
  multiple: true;
  onSelectChange: (values: string[]) => void;
  renderValue?: (value: string[]) => React.ReactNode;
}

interface SingleSelectProps {
  selectValue: string;
  onSelectChange: (values: string) => void;
  multiple?: never;
  renderValue?: (value: string) => React.ReactNode;
}

type SelectProps = SingleSelectProps | MultipleSelectProps;

const Select: React.FC<SelectProps> = ({
  selectValue,
  multiple,
  onSelectChange,
  renderValue,
  children,
}) => {
  return (
{
  multiple ?
    <MultipleSelect
      selectValue={selectValue}
      onSelectChange={onSelectChange}
      renderValue={renderValue}
    >
      {children}
    </MultipleSelect>
    :
    <SingleSelect
      selectValue={selectValue}
      onSelectChange={onSelectChange}
      renderValue={renderValue}
    >
      {children}
    </SingleSelect>
  );
};
export default Select;
```

and I want to be able to use my component similarly to how the native html `<select>` is used. Like so:

```
<Select selectValue={selectValue} onSelectChange={onSelectChange} multiple>
  {options}
</Select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. By defining the kind TypeScript is aware of the type of selectValue and other that might change.

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import MultipleSelect from './MultipleSelect';
import SingleSelect from './SingleSelect';


type SelectProps = {
    kind: 'multiple',
    selectValue: string[];
    onSelectChange: (values: string[]) => void;
    renderValue?: (value: string[]) => React.ReactNode;
} | {
    kind: 'single',
    selectValue: string;
    onSelectChange: (values: string) => void;
    renderValue?: (value: string) => React.ReactNode;

}

const Selector = (props: SelectProps, children): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
        {
        props.kind === 'multiple' 
        ?
            <MultipleSelect
            selectValue={props.selectValue}
            onSelectChange={props.onSelectChange}
            renderValue={props.renderValue}
            >
            {children}
            </MultipleSelect>
        :
            <SingleSelect
            selectValue={props.selectValue}
            onSelectChange={props.onSelectChange}
            renderValue={props.renderValue}
            >
            {children}
            </SingleSelect>
        
        }
    </>
  )
}

export default Selector
```

Comment: How is this different from having the prop multiple and defining that as True or Never? Is its because its optional? I want to be able to write my component like so: `<Select ...otherProps multiple>` to mimic the use of the native html `<select>`

Comment: In my example code if you hover over props.selectValue in the MultipleSelect you see that TypeScript knows that the type is an array of strings. In your second block of code TypeScript thinks it's an any. I haven't tried using the component like you mentioned with: <Select... etc.

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to be able to figure that out on my end. Which version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: I'm using TypeScript 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in`to check if multiple is set like so:

```
type MultipleSelectProps = {
  multiple: true;
  value: string[];
  onChange: (newValue: string[]) => void;
};

type SingleSelectProps = {
  value: string;
  onChange: (newValue: string) => void;
};

type SelectProps = MultipleSelectProps | SingleSelectProps;

function SingleSelect(props: SingleSelectProps) {
  return null;
}

function MultiSelect(props: MultipleSelectProps) {
  return null;
}

function Select(props: SelectProps) {
  return "multiple" in props ? (
    <MultiSelect {...props} />
  ) : (
    <SingleSelect {...props} />
  );
}
```

Comment: I still get the error `Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.ts(2322)`. I Don't want to use propspreading(lint rule), is it possible without?

Comment: where are you getting this error? this example runs error free for me but there might be some other issues... What TS version are you using?

Comment: TypeScript is v4.2.4. The only difference between how you wrote it and the code that gives me the error is that you are using prop spreading. E.g `{...props}`. Do you not get an error if you pass the props in normaly?

Comment: Sounds like you are destructuring your value prop... if you are destructuring value before you make the check for `multiple` ts can't narrow down the type of value.

Comment: Seems like you are right. Is it possible to make ts narrow down the types when destructuring in the component arguments? E.g `({selectValue, onSelectChange, renderValue, multiple}) => { // component code }`